# The right side of the window is cut-off

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I am using eclipse widgets to create simple window with the TreeView within it and several panels. My java code which creates window is here:

```
protected void createContents() {
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.verticalSpacing = 0;
    gridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
    gridLayout.marginHeight = 0;
    gridLayout.marginBottom = 1;
    setLayout(gridLayout);

    setText("Order Inspector");
    setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, 500);
    setImage(SGuiUtil.getIconForShell());

    Composite searchMargin = new Composite(this, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout searchMarginLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    searchMarginLayout.marginHeight = 0;
    searchMarginLayout.marginTop = 5;
    searchMarginLayout.marginBottom = 4;
    searchMarginLayout.horizontalSpacing = 0; //10;
    searchMargin.setLayout(searchMarginLayout);
    final GridData gd_searchMargin = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false);
    searchMargin.setLayoutData(gd_searchMargin);

    searchText = new Text(searchMargin, SWT.SEARCH | SWT.ICON_SEARCH | SWT.ICON_CANCEL | SWT.BORDER);
    searchText.setMessage("Search");
    final GridData gd_searchText = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);
    searchText.setLayoutData(gd_searchText);


    ToolBar inspectorToolBar = new ToolBar(searchMargin, SWT.RIGHT);
    viewOptionsToolItem = new ToolItem(inspectorToolBar, SWT.PUSH);
    viewOptionsToolItem.setImage(Images.imageWithName("/com/images/switch.png"));
    viewOptionsToolItem.setToolTipText("Inspector View Options");
    helpToolItem = new ToolItem(inspectorToolBar, SWT.PUSH);
    helpToolItem.setImage(Images.imageWithName("/com/images/icons/question-white.png"));
    helpToolItem.setToolTipText("Inspector help");


    hintText = new Label(this, SWT.WRAP);
    hintText.setText("");
    hintText.setLayoutData(notVisibleGridData());
    hintText.setVisible(false);

    treeViewer = new TreeViewer(this, SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.H_SCROLL); // | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    treeViewer.setAutoExpandLevel(0);
    treeViewer.setUseHashlookup(false);

    inspectorRowFilter = new InspectorRowFilter(searchText);

    Tree tree = treeViewer.getTree();
    tree.setLinesVisible(true);
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
    tree.setLayoutData(treeGridData());

    propertyTableColumn = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.NONE);
    propertyTableColumn.setText("Property");

    valueTableColumn = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.NONE);
    valueTableColumn.setText("Value");
}
```

And the result is the window with cut-off right side:

[image: Here is the screen of window with cut-off right side].

How to fix please?

Comment: Your Tree is a Composite. Did you remember to set a layout on it and layout data for its child TreeColumns?

Comment: How to do it please? This is all code I have for window creation.

Comment: That `setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, 500)` looks like it probably sets the width. But since we don't know what it does I can't say for sure.

Comment: This call sets window size, but I need to set size of Grid with 2 colums somehow